# delay in between chain of promises

Tags: node.js

everyone, I have been trying out a delay of 8secs within the chain of promises i.e promise.all.
But unfortunately, it's not executing the way I want it to execute it.
I want a delay of 8secs between an array of promises and I have tried out some code. Anyone any idea how to put it or where I am going wrong?

```
var cron = require('node-cron');
let cron_schedule="* * * * *";
let max_Request = 10,requestProcess = [];
let checkCronJob = () => {
    while (max_Request > 0){
       requestProcess.push(processRequest(produce))
       requestProcess.push(delay(8000));
    }
    return Promise.all(requestProcess).then((result) => {
         console.log(result);
    });
}

var delay = function () {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(true)
        }, 8000);
    });
    return promise;
}
let processRequest = async (produce) => {
     max_Request--;
     return await Promise.resolve(true);
}

checkCronJob();
```

"processRequest" will return a promise and after that, I added a delay of 8secs but it is actually executing all the promises in one go after a delay of 8secs.
I wanted the promises to execute within the delay of 8secs.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to do:

```
var delay = promise => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        promise.then(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(true)
            }, 8000);
        });
    });
}


var recursiveDelay = n => {
    delay(processRequest(produce)).then(() => { if(n > 0)  recursiveDelay(n-1)});
}

recursiveDelay(10);
```

Comment: I added that line

Comment: @ Alexandre Senges no

Comment: @SwetaSharma what's the error message? The problem is likely not in your snippet

Comment: there is no error it's just there is no delay between promises. It is executing the promises in one go and then it is keeping a delay of 8secs but I want in between the execution of each promises

Comment: Ok your question wasn't clear, I update my answer, check back in a few minutes

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @SwetaSharma I couldn't try it because I don't have the rest of your code but that should be the idea

Comment: @Alexandre Senges  let me edit the code for you then

Answer (score 0):

Promises are executed *immediately*, if you want to ensure a delay before starting the next action then you can't setup the promises like you are.

You would need to do something like:

```
while (max_Request > 0) {
  await processRequest(produce);
  await delay(8000);
  max_Request--;
}
```

If you can't use `async` / `await`, then it's slightly uglier

```
let req;
while (max_Request > 0) {
  if (!req) {
    req = processRequest(produce);
  } else {
    req.then(processRequest(produce));
  }
  req.then(delay(8000));
  max_Request--;
}
return req.then(console.log);
```

Comment: @SwetaSharma yeah, so make the function you call this code in `async`.

Comment: getMaxRequest(produce)
        .then(result => {
            console.log("for result");
            console.log(result);
        });

let getMaxRequest = async (produce) => {
    while (max_Request > 0){
        await processRequest(produce);
        await delay(8000);
    }
}

Comment: @SwetaSharma I've added a non `async` / `await` version too.

Comment: @SwetaSharma make `checkCronJob` `async` and then you can use the code in my first example. Is there a result that you get at the end of all the Promises? You appear to log something out but I don't see in your code how that would produce anything since they're chained but you don't pass the previous result to the next.